# Why can't I cast a SQL Server datetime to a Spark SQL date on an Azure Synapse Delta Lake?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I have created a Delta Table on a Spark Database in my Azure Synapse Data Lake. When I try to populate it by merging a temporal view table obtained from a .parquet file that contains data from a SQL Server table i get the following error for every single field that is a DATETIME in SQL Server and that I intend to parse to DATE in Spark SQL:

> Error: cannot resolve 'CAST(w2.myDate AS DATE)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast int to date; line 1 pos 0'

If I comment every single datetime field in the MERGE query it works fine, but it won't let me cast the DATETIME to DATE. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: *"cannot cast int to date"* Seems pretty explicit. It appears that `myDate` is an `int`, not a `datetime`.

Comment: @Larnu I have checked several times in my SQL Server DB. It is defined as DateTime

Comment: Is your import schema correct?  You may well have the columns out of order

Comment: @iamdave It probably has something to do with that, because I have managed right now to do the merge in other tables successfully. Thank you!